# problema ssl let's encrypt certificado ssl

Tags: html5, ssl

todo correcto al instalarlo funciona perfecto pero a la hora de compartí desde mi sitio web a redes sociales en http si imprime el contenido de los meta pero en https no imprime nada solo el enlace de la web. los enlace los e depurado "developer" y en https me marca error. cuando http me va todo correcto. mismo código, sin modificar nada,.

```
<meta name="description"                content="[ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION]">
<meta name="author"                     content="[AUTHOR_NAME_OF_THE_ARTICLE]">
<meta property="og:locale"              content="en_US"/>
<meta property="og:type"                content="article"/>
<meta property="og:title"               content="[ARTICLE_TITLE]"/>
<meta property="og:description"         content="[ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION]"/>
<meta property="og:url"                 content="[ARTICLE_URL]"/>
<meta property="og:site_name"           content="[WEBSITE_NAME]"/>
<meta property="article:publisher"      content=""/>
<meta property="article:published_time" content="[PUBLISHED_TIME_OF_YOUR_ARTICLE Ex: 2015-12-08T20:50:00Z]"/>
<meta property="og:image"               content="[MAIN_IMAGE_URL]"/>
<meta name="twitter:title"              content="[ARTICLE_TITLE]"/>
<meta name="twitter:description"        content="[ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION]"/>
<meta name="twitter:image"              content="[MAIN_IMAGE_URL]"/>
<meta name="twitter:site"               content="@[TWITTER_USERNAME]"/>
<meta name="twitter:creator"            content="@[TWITTER_USERNAME]"/>
<meta name="twitter:via"                content="[TWITTER_USERNAME]"/>
<meta name="twitter:card"               content="photo"/>
<meta name="twitter:url"                content="[ARTICLE_URL]"/>
```

me tiene hablando solo no si es problema del servidor del código o del ssl
pero el problema empezó al instalar el certificado  ssl

---

la redirección si la hace bien con .htaccess. y lo de generar el certificado ssl no lo entiendo. el navegador me valida como seguro asta hay todo bien el problema esta a la hora de compartir en rede sociales

este es el error que me información developers.facebook
 Advertencias que deberían solucionarse Propiedad inferida La propiedad "og:image" debe proporcionarse de forma explícita, incluso si puede deducirse su valor a partir de otras etiquetas. Faltan propiedades Faltan las siguientes propiedades obligatorias: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id SSL Error Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid. Error de cURL Error de cURL: 60 (SSL_CACERT) – Txuti hace 14 minutos

Comment: Hola!, ¿Has intentado realizar una redirección http a https?

Comment: generastes tu certificado ssl?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas... ya solucione el problema, se trataba que era un error de certificado en los navegadores
las solución fue que una ves instales el certificado ssl let's encrypt, y redireccionar con (.htaccess) también debes instalar el CA Certificate. mas información [aquí](https://whatsmychaincert.com/)
gracias y saludos